# Script Code For Program Not Working [High Schooler]

Tags: javascript, html

I am a 11th grade student working on a JavaScript class. I am having issues with an assignment and I was wondering could anyone help me fix it. I am working on a site called *neocities.org.* The script code I got off a Youtube video tutorial. The issue occurs when I view the code in browser the game does not work the buttons do not do anything. I have ran through the code 3 times and cannot find the issue. 
Its code that makes a Blackjack game. (the playing card game). 
If anyone could point out the issue I would appreciate it.

```js
< script >
  function getTheSuit()
  (
    suit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1
    if (suit == 1)
      (
        return "Hearts";
      )
    if (suit == 2)
      (
        return "Diamonds";
      )
    if (suit == 3)
      (
        return "Spades";
      )
    if (suit == 4)
      (
        return "Clubs";
      )
  )

function getACard(turn)
(
  card = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1 suit = getTheSuit();
  if (card == 1)
    (
      return 11;
    )
  if (card > 10)
    (
      return 10;
    )
  var counter = 0;

  function GenerateNewCard()
  (
    counter += 1;
    var d = document.getElementById("HUM").innerHTML = "";
    var e = document.getElementById("COMP").innerHTML = "";
    var f = document.getElementById("COUNT").innerHTML = counter;
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("dealer").value = 0);
    var res = document.getElementById("dealer");
    var aa = parseInt(document.getElementById("you").value = 0);
    var resa = document.getElementById("you"); resa.value = a + getACard("You"); res.value = aa + getACard("Dealer");
  )
  function COMPUTOR()
  (
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("dealer").value);
    var res = document.getElementById("dealer");
    while (res.value < 17)
      (
        var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("dealer").value; res.value = b + getACard("Dealer");)
      )

    function HUMAN()
    (
      var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("you").value);
      var res = document.getElementById("you"); res.value = a + getACard("You");
      if (res.value > 21)
        (
          whoWonC += 1; document.getElementById("COMPW").innerHTML = whoWonC;
          var a = document.getElementById("COMP").innerHTML = "I WIN";
        )
    ) var whoWonH = 0
    var whoWonC = 0

    function determineWinner()
    (

      var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("you").value);
      var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("dealer").value);
      if (b > 21)
        (
          whoWonH += 1 document.getElementById("HUMW").innerHTML = whoWonH;
          var winner = document.getElementById("HUM").innerHTML = "I WIN";
          return;
        )
      if (a == b)
        (
          var a = document.getElementById("HUM").innerHTML = "TIE";
          var b = document.getElementById("COMP").innerHTML = "TIE";
        )
      if (a > b)
        (
          whoWonH += 1; document.getElementById("HUMW").innerHTML = whoWonH;
          var a = document.getElementById("HUM").innerHTML = "I WIN";
        )
      if (b > a)
        (
          whoWonC += 1; document.getElementById("COMPW").innerHTML = whoWonC;
          var g = document.getElementById("COMP").innerHTML = "I WIN";
        )
    )

    <
    /script>
```

it.

Comment: That's not how you declare functions, the basic form is `function () {}`, not `function () ()`. Secondly, where are you calling any of these functions?

Comment: Your JavaScript is full of syntax errors, so the code probably is unable to be interpreted and run. Your best bet is to look at your developer's console (F12) and look at the errors. You may be able to figure out a lot of the errors on your own. If you get stuck on a specific error, you should ask about that. It's really hard to debug a whole program in the StackOverflow format.

Comment: I'd suggest starting out with some simpler code so you can get the basic syntax down.